# Swipe to switch tab selection

Tags: android, gesture, swipe

I have an application that is a Tab activity with various tabs that load an Activity. I would like to add swipe gesturing to switch between tabs, on both the tab control itself and each activity loaded in a tab.  Is something like this possible? I'm not sure at what "depth" the gesture is listened to when you're making gestures on an Activity hosted in the tab control, or if the inner activities would have to pass data to the Tab Host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible; you'll need to write a custom layout and override [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) to decide whether to dispatch gestures through to the children . See [HorizontalPager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager)'s source for details on how you could go about doing that. You actually may just want to use HorizontalPager straight up (there's a demo on simulating tabs with it), as I think the scrolling content makes it much clearer that you can swipe between tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a gesture detector. As far as I know it listens to gestures "globally". To restrict it to the tab you could check whether the gesture has occurred inside the boundaries of the tab.

> **GestureDetector**
>
> Detects various gestures and events
>   using the supplied MotionEvents. The
>   GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
>   callback will notify users when a
>   particular motion event has occurred.
>   This class should only be used with
>   MotionEvents reported via touch (don't
>   use for trackball events). To use this
>   class:

- Create an instance of the
  GestureDetector for your View In the
  nTouchEvent(MotionEvent) method
  ensure you call
- onTouchEvent(MotionEvent). The
  methods defined in your callback will
  be executed when the events occur

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

**Swipe Gesture**

This page shows how to recognize a swipe-gesture using the GestureDetector:
http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/swipe-action-and-viewflipper-in-android.html

Comment: This is helpful info on GestureDetector, but I'm still not sure how to have the gesture detection flow through to the Activities hosted in the tabs. The Gesture Detector only functions in the space not taking up by an activity in a tab.