# I want to be able to swipe left and right in an Android TabView to switch between tabs

Tags: android, swipe, tabview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swipe to switch tab selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636349/swipe-to-switch-tab-selection)

I am trying to implement a TabView in Android where the user can swipe left or right to change tabs. This is similar to Google Music where the tabs (ie. music, artists, genre) are at the top and you can either click one of those or swipe left or right to go to the adjacent tab. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)