# new android market layout

Tags: android, android-layout

the new android market does introduce a tab like control, as seen in these pictures [image][image]

what control is it? the one saying "Editors Choice" in dark green, you could swipe it in the main activity.

i wanna know the name so i can research how to use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 'Scrollable Tab'

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

http://developer.android.com/design/media/tabs_scrolly.mp4

Scroll down to scrolling tabs:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html

They talk about implementation details here:

[Swipe to switch tab selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636349/swipe-to-switch-tab-selection)

And as Mark mentioned a ViewPagerIndicator implementation here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Actually, considering that the body area is a `ViewPager` (AFAIK), I'm not completely convinced that "scrollable tab" is really implemented as a `TabWidget`. It might be something more along the lines of Jake Wharton's [`ViewPagerIndicator`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) stuff.

Comment: Sure it will probably be easier in that scenario as well, I've always found tabwidgets fidgety.

Comment: is there any native controls for it? can't seem to find a native way to do it anywhere.

Comment: Nope believe you will have to roll a custom view, take a look at that ViewPagerIndicator it looks like it'll do what you want